# error while drawing currents in circuitikz

Tags: errors, labels, circuitikz

This is my first complete circuit in circuitiks. I'm trying to draw a circuit to show Kirchoff's Law. I was able to draw the nodes and voltages, but putting currents with arrow is giving me trouble.

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
  \usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath}
  \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
  \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
  \setlength\PreviewBorder{50pt}%

  \begin{document}


  \begin{tikzpicture} [auto, circuitikz]

  %produces error. Without i=$I$, it works
  \draw (0,0) to [R=$R_1$, v_=$v_1$, i=$I$, *-*] (2,0)
              -| (3,-1) 
              to [R=$R_2$, v_=$v_2$, *-*] (3,-3)
              |- (-1,-4) 
              to [battery, l = $V$, *-*] (-1,0)
              -- (0,0)
        (1,-2) node[scale=6]{$\circlearrowright$}
        (1,-2) node{$I$};

  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

**The error that I'm getting is "! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `south' (in 'south')."**

Secondly, I would like to move the voltage slightly away from the resistors. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

This solution uses `circuitikz` environment rather than `tikzpicutre` environment, then the errors are gone. To move the v1 away from the resistor, `raisebox{neg height}{content}` is used while for the `v2` only `\,\,` is used.

[image]

Code

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
  \usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath}
  \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
  \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
  \setlength\PreviewBorder{50pt}%

  \begin{document}


  \begin{circuitikz} 
  %produces error. Without i=$I$, it works
  \draw (0,0) to [R=$R_1$,v_=\raisebox{-10pt}{$v_1$}, i=$I$, *-*] (2,0)
              -| (3,-1) 
              to [R=$R_2$, v_={$v_2$\,\,}, *-*] (3,-3)
              |- (-1,-4) 
              to [battery, v_ = $V$, *-*] (-1,0)
              -- (0,0)
        (1,-2) node[scale=6]{$\circlearrowright$}
        (1,-2) node{$I$};
  \end{circuitikz}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: It is working also with `tikzpicture` environment; in particular, notice that the `tikzpicture` environment is absolutely mandatory while performing externalizations, see [Compiling CircuiTikZ with -shell-escape (pdflatex)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82064/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino -- Yes, you are right. But I did confirm the problem while trying to solve the OP's problem when investigating what went wrong. Then, my instinct was to try `circuitikz` instead and then the errors went disappeared. Just now, after reading your comment and link, I recheck my code and it does work. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the cause of the original error message was the `auto` option, which seems to be incompatible with the way currents are typeset in `circuitikz`. I ran into the same problem and had to debug for quite some time before I found out that the culprit was a
`\tikzset{auto}`
that I had in the file header, that I needed for a number of other tikz figures in the same document. Since I wanted to keep this default setting in the document, I ended up doing
`\begin{circuitikz}[auto=false]`
for the few `circuitikz` illustrations I had.