# How to avoid the poles of the voltages to overlap the resistors?

Tags: labels

Using this code in circuitkz I get this circuit

[image]

```
 \begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \ctikzset {voltage/distance from node=1};
    \draw 
     (0,0) to[battery,l=V] (0,2)
     to[R,l^=$R_1$,v=$V_1$] (4,2)
     to[R,l=$R_2$,v=$V_2$] (4,0)
     (4,0) -- (0,0)
    ;
    \end {circuitikz}
```

How can I move V1 and V2 labels to the left and down, both the label themselves and the poles? It's so nasty to get the poles overlapping the resistors!!

Answer (score 3):

Adjust the value of  `\ctikzset {voltage/distance from node=0.5}`, say 0.5 or 0.8.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \ctikzset {voltage/distance from node=0.5}
 \begin{circuitikz}%[american]
    \draw 
     (0,0) to[battery,l=V] (0,2)
     to[R,l^=$R_1$,v=$V_1$] (4,2)
     to[R,l=$R_2$,v=$V_2$] (4,0)
     (4,0) -- (0,0)
    ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to fix just the poles overlapping. I'd need to displace V labels as well. Thnx.

Comment: A tricky solution was to define "opens" in the circuit: `\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\ctikzset {voltage/distance from node=0.8};
\draw 
 (0,0) to[battery,l=V] (0,4)
 to[R,l^=$R_1$] (6,4)
 to[R,l=$R_2$] (6,0)
 (2,3.5) to[open,v=$V_1$] (4,3.5)
 (5.5,3) to[open,v=$V_2$] (5.5,1)
 (6,0) -- (0,0)
;
\end {circuitikz}`

Comment: Ya, use the open circuit skill with different coordinates, but still need `distance from node=0.8`, right? Did you try `distance from node=1` with the tricky solution?

Comment: Sorry, you had two follow-ups. As to the first question, here is my solution -- Use of `raisebox` and `hspace` skills. For example  `to[R,l^=$R_1$,v=\raisebox{-20pt}{$V_1$}] (4,2)`
     `to[R,l=$R_2$,v=\hspace{-20pt} $V_2$] (4,0)`. You may need to change the -20pt to suit your needs.  Or further reading http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161476/34618

Comment: both `distance from node`and `\raisebox` `\hspace` worked well! Now it looks much better!! Anyway, I noticed poles don't move down \ left as the voltage labels do. They don't seem to be affected by `\hspace` or `\raisebox`. Can they move along the voltage labels?

Comment: My view is that `distance from node` controls the polarity because the package provides american (polarity) and european (curve arrow) style. Thus label is not tied together with the polarity. Polairty is a notion alone the conductor while labels can be allocated at all directions. FYI, there is also `voltage/european label distance` written in the manual on page 38. This would mean, to me, these are not tied together too, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\psset{dipolestyle = zigzag}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.8,0)(10.75,6.75)
  \pnodes{P}(0,0)(0,6)(4,5.7)(6,5.7)(10,6)(9.7,4)(9.7,2)(10,0)
  \battery[labeloffset = -22pt](P1)(P0){$V$}
  \resistor[labeloffset = 16pt](P1)(P4){\large $R_{1}$}
  \resistor[labeloffset = -17pt](P1)(P4){\large $V_{1}$}
  \rput(P2){$+$}
  \rput(P3){$-$}
  \resistor[labeloffset = 16pt](P4)(P7){\large $R_{2}$}
  \resistor[labeloffset = -17pt](P4)(P7){\large $V_{2}$}
  \rput(P5){$+$}
  \rput(P6){$-$}
  \wire(P7)(P0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: 1. No need to reinvent the wheel. Tension label and polarity sign are already provided by the package. 2. The polarity of the battery must be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the number of keystrokes used in the existing PSTricks answer.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\psset
{
    dipolestyle=zigzag,
    labeloffset=.8,
    tensionstyle=pm,
    tensionoffset=-.8,
    tensionlabeloffset=-.8,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(8,6)
    \pnodes{P}(1,0)(1,5)(7,5)(7,0)
    \vdc[labeloffset=-.8](P1)(P0){$V$}
    \resistor[tensionlabel=$V_1$](P1)(P2){$R_1$}
    \resistor[tensionlabel=$V_2$](P2)(P3){$R_2$}
    \wire(P3)(P0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

If you want to use PSTricks rather than TikZ, make sure you compile it with either

- `xelatex` or
- `latex` followed by `dvips` followed by `ps2pdf`.

At the end, you will get a diagram (in PDF) which you can import from within your main TeX file via `\includegraphics` and the main TeX file can be compiled with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Excuse me, I'm newbiw in Latex. So, Must I change package circuitikz by pst-circ? Couldn't I do using circuitikz?