# Are the TikZ libraries cd and external incompatible with one another?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, tikz-cd

Is there a way to use the `TikZ` libraries `cd` and `external` together?
This does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & B \\ & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
Runaway argument?

! File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture.
```

I’m using `TikZ/PGF` version 3.0.0 and `tikz-cd` version 0.9b.

Comment: I would say yes according to [Compiling CircuiTikZ with -shell-escape (pdflatex)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82064/13304), but I might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you, but even after reading your linked answer, I don’t understand how to make it work. Replacing `tikzcd` with `tikzpicture` does not work. See Section 3.1 on page 11 of the `tikz-cd` manual (version 0.9b, of March 8, 2014). Or am I doing something wrong? Have you tried my example? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I had a look, but honestly requires too much work and at the moment I'm lacking time. Basically, you can not replace `tikzcd` environment with `tikzpicture` because all definitions like `\arrow` are initialized when `tikzcd` begins. I would suggest you to contact the package author for this problem.

Comment: Thank you, Claudio! That’s exactly what I thought. Oddly enough, I can’t find a contact information for the author, Florêncio Neves.

Comment: Perhaps you can leave [him](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12744/florencio-neves) a message in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) with `@profile-name`syntax.

Comment: Your initial code does not compile for me.  Where is the `cd` tikzlibrary defined?  I thought `tikz-cd` was a separate package, not a TikZ library.

Comment: @AndrewStacey `tikz-cd` is distributed separately, but the current version (v0.9b, which requires `pgf` v3.0.0) is implemented as a library, and `tikz-cd.sty` now only contains `\usetikzlibrary{cd}`.

Comment: @MarcoVarisco I see.  I've just updated TL2013 on my machine so I'll take another look.

Comment: Hello @MarcoVarisco , Please, if you are around, I really think that you should move your solution from the question to the answer, because the solution works just great and I am using it. The only thing is, when you're there, add `[baseline=0pt]` to the `\begin{tikzpicture}` so that the equation number gets placed correctly ;)

Comment: Hi, @tohecz, done! I actually already had a baseline adjustment in my answer. But `[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]` seems to work better for me. As for me, I am not using my own solution, which is Not A Good Idea according to @LoopSpace, but I am using the solution he provided.

Comment: @MarcoVarisco Upvoted! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is the same as that in [Problem with environment expansion and the Tikz external library.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/problem-with-environment-expansion-and-the-tikz-external-library) in that TeX does not see the `\end{tikzpicture}` inside the `\end{tikzcd}`.  The solution in [Problem with environment expansion and the Tikz external library.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/problem-with-environment-expansion-and-the-tikz-external-library) is to pack everything inside a macro to ensure that the customised end-of-environment is expanded before TeX starts gobbling so that the hidden `\end{tikzpicture}` is revealed.  The adaptation of that in the question above is not the same because it adds an extra `\end{tikzpicture}` instead of unpacking the hidden one, and this leads to nesting of TikZ pictures which is Not A Good Idea.

(Nonetheless, just because something is not a good idea doesn't mean that it isn't the best idea, just that it should be used with extreme caution.)

If all your pictures are `tikzcd` environments then it seems that the right solution might be to tell TeX to look for `tikzcd` instead of `tikzpicture`.  This is a reasonable thing to try to do because the first thing that `\begin{tikzcd}` does is to start a `tikzpicture` and the last thing that `\end{tikzcd}` does is to end it.  However, my experiments at trying to change all `tikzpicture`s in the externalisation code to `tikzcd` didn't work so I'm abandoning this for the time being (what would be nice would be an adaptation of the externalisation library that worked for *any* environment, not just `tikzpicture`s).

Here's an adaptation of your adaptation of my answer to the linked question which instead of wrapping the `tikzcd` environment in a `tikzpicture` simply exposes the inner `tikzpicture`.  Well, except that it doesn't since the inner `tikzpicture` is written as `\tikzpicture ... \endtikzpicture` which wouldn't match so we have to redefine the `tikzcd` environment to make the `\tikzpicture` and `\endtikzpicture` into `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`.  Elegant, it ain't, but it does avoid the nesting issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171931/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,external}
\tikzexternalize

\makeatletter
\def\tikzcd@[#1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[/tikz/commutative diagrams/.cd,every diagram,#1]%
  \ifx\arrow\tikzcd@arrow%
    \pgfutil@packageerror{tikz-cd}{Diagrams cannot be nested}{}
  \fi%
  \let\arrow\tikzcd@arrow%
  \let\ar\tikzcd@arrow%
  \def\rar{\tikzcd@xar{r}}%
  \def\lar{\tikzcd@xar{l}}%
  \def\dar{\tikzcd@xar{d}}%
  \def\uar{\tikzcd@xar{u}}%
  \def\urar{\tikzcd@xar{ur}}%
  \def\ular{\tikzcd@xar{ul}}%
  \def\drar{\tikzcd@xar{dr}}%
  \def\dlar{\tikzcd@xar{dl}}%
  \global\let\tikzcd@savedpaths\pgfutil@empty%
  \matrix[/tikz/matrix of \iftikzcd@mathmode math \fi nodes,
          /tikz/every cell/.append code={\tikzcdset{every cell}},
          /tikz/commutative diagrams/.cd,every matrix]%
  \bgroup}

\def\endtikzcd{%
  \pgfmatrixendrow\egroup%
  \pgfextra{\global\let\tikzcdmatrixname\tikzlastnode};%
  \tikzcdset{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-row diagram/.try}%
  \begingroup%
    \tikzcd@enablequotes%
    \tikzcd@patcherrmsg%
    \tikzcd@savedpaths%
  \endgroup%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi}


\NewEnviron{mytikzcd}[1][]{%
  \def\@temp{\tikzcd@[#1]\BODY}%
  \expandafter\@temp\endtikzcd
}
\makeatother

\def\temp{&} \catcode`&=\active \let&=\temp
\begin{document}

\begin{mytikzcd}
  A \arrow{rd} \arrow{r}{\phi} & B \\ & C
\end{mytikzcd}

\begin{mytikzcd}
  A \arrow{rd} \arrow{r}{\phi} & B \\ & C
\end{mytikzcd}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately your code does not produce the right output for me. [Here](http://imgur.com/Iphe8Ho)’s what I get. It probably has to do with the fact that we’re using different versions of `tikz-cd`.

I do agree that what would be **really** nice is “an adaptation of the externalisation library that worked for any environment, not just `tikzpicture`s.”

Comment: @MarcoVarisco One problem with testing externalisation is checking that the externalised graphics are from the _current_ run, not the previous one.  I think that's what happened here.  I've fixed my hack, by making it even more hacky.  It's definitely Not Elegant, but it fixes the problem you saw ... I think.

Comment: Is there a way to overwrite the existing tikzcd environment instead of having to use one with a new name? I tried `\RenewEnviron{tikzcd}…` but I get the error `File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture`. Thanks!

Comment: I experience a problem running this code: ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "foo-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{fo
o}\input{foo}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'foo-figure0' (expected 
one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls
. -- But I used 'pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex'. Any hints?

Comment: I get the exact same problem as user44400.

Comment: I'm a bit worried by the global definition of `\def\temp{&} \catcode\`&=\active \let&=\temp`: is it possible to redefine it locally, to avoid disturbing other packages? I created my own question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632643/how-to-avoid-redefining-ampersand-globally

Answer (score 14):

When I originally answered this, `external` was the only option available. Fortunately, that is no longer the case. Two new options for externalisation are now available from a CTAN mirror near you: `memoize` and `robust-externalize`.

Here's a solution using `memoize`, with `tikzcd` setup thanks to [`memoize`'s author](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64689784#64689784).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{memoize}
\mmzset{%
  path={dir=memos},
  mkdir,
  % Sašo Živanović: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64689784#64689784
  auto={tikzcd}{memoize,verbatim},
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {node};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & B \\ & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

After a single compilation, the images are `memoized` as part of the production of the main PDF. At this point, they appear as extra pages, in addition to being produced in the appropriate location in the document.

[image: results of single compilation]

On the second compilation, the *externs* are extracted into separate PDF files and are now included in the main PDF, without requiring recompilation. The code for the images will be recompiled only if it changes or some further condition holds. (E.g. if you delete the PDFs or instruct `memoize` to do recompile or whatever.)

[image: result of second compilation, using memoized images]

## Original answer

This solution does not allow you to externalise diagrams produced using the `tikzcd` environment but it does allow you to externalise *other* `tikz` pictures in your document. It is based on a workaround mentioned in the `tikz` manual in section 50.8.2 (pages 627-8). To make its use more convenient, `etoolbox` is used to patch the `tikzcd` environment. Essentially, this turns externalisation off at the beginning of `tikzcd` environments and then switches it back on again at their ends.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
  \tikzexternalize
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzcd}{\tikzexternaldisable}
\AtEndEnvironment{tikzcd}{\tikzexternalenable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {node};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & B \\ & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

On the first run, `pdflatex --shell-escape <filename>.tex` includes this output:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "<filename>-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalreal
job{<filename>}\input{<filename>}"' ========
```

`<filename>-figure0.pdf` looks like this:

[image: Externalised picture]

Subsequent runs include the output:

```
===== Image '<filename>-figure0' is up-to-date. ======
```

The PDF combines the externalised image from `<filename>-figure0.pdf` with the one produced from `tikzcd` on the fly:

[image: One picture externalised; one not]

How helpful this is will depend on what proportion of your pictures are `tikzcd`. If the answer is 100%, it will obviously be of no use at all. On the other hand, if the answer is less than 100%, there may be something to be said for it.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, almost all my pictures are `tikzcd`, but it’s a helpful trick nonetheless.

Comment: @MarcoVarisco Too bad. Maybe it will help somebody else ;).

Answer (score 8):

Here’s one solution that works with the `external` library and that I hadn’t thought of before.
We can put the `tikzcd` environment inside a `tizkpicture`’s node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & B \\ & C
  \end{tikzcd}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To get spacing and alignment right, the following options seem to work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]
  \node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] {\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & B \\ & C
  \end{tikzcd}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So combining this with [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/loop-space)’s excellent [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15614/2072) to a related question, we get:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, environ}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, external}
\tikzexternalize

\def\temp{&} \catcode`&=\active \let&=\temp

\NewEnviron{mycd}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]
    \node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] {\begin{tikzcd}[#1]
      \BODY
    \end{tikzcd}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{mycd}[row sep=huge]
  A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & B \\ & C
\end{mycd}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

It still feels like a dirty hack to me. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Thank you! This works well for me. However, in your solution, \BODY is expanded to late, and so the figures are not rebuilt if the content is changed. (Change to `\tikzset{external/up to date check=diff}` in order to see that \BODY is not expanded yet in the .md5 files).

Comment: Since my adjusted code did not fit into the comment box I have added [another answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362104/46552)

Comment: Is there a solution to avoid redefining `&` globally? I'm worried to disturb other packages, unfortunately I can't find any solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632643/how-to-avoid-redefining-ampersand-globally

Answer (score 6):

I had to adjust [Marco Varisco](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208524/46552)'s answer, in order to get the figure automatically rebuilt on change. Furthermore, I let the baseline of the artificial tikzpicture be on the height of the tikzcd's baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, environ, etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, external}
\tikzexternalize
% activate the following such that you can check the macro expansion in
% *-figure0.md5 manually
%\tikzset{external/up to date check=diff}


\def\temp{&} \catcode`&=\active \let&=\temp

\newcommand{\mytikzcdcontext}[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(maintikzcdnode.base)]
    \node (maintikzcdnode) [inner sep=0, outer sep=0] {\begin{tikzcd}[#2]
        #1
    \end{tikzcd}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\NewEnviron{mytikzcd}[1][]{%
% In the following, we need \BODY to expanded before \mytikzcdcontext
% such that the md5 function gets the tikzcd content with \BODY expanded.
% Howerver, expand it only once, because the \tikz-macros aren't
% defined at this point yet. The same thing holds for the arguments to
% the tikzcd-environment.
\def\myargs{#1}%
\edef\mydiagram{\noexpand\mytikzcdcontext{\expandonce\BODY}{\expandonce\myargs}}%
\mydiagram%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{mytikzcd}[row sep=huge,baseline = (B.base)]
  A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & |[alias=B]| B \\ & C
\end{mytikzcd}
\hbox{sharing a baseline with } B
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I started using this and it works great, but I have the feeling that whenever I add or remove a diagram, compilation takes a lot time, probably because all the later diagrams have to be recompiled since the numbering is off. Can this be avoided somehow? Or probably it's an issue with tikz-external which is independent of this tikz-cd hack?

Comment: @user313032: this is an issue with externalize in general because the filenames essentially only consist of a name prefix and an integer counter. You can avoid it by giving each tikz figure an explicit name or by setting `\tikzsetfigurename{..}` regularly, e.g. to something different for on each new subsection.

Comment: ahh interesting! how can I give names to figures?

Comment: ahh probably you mean the command `tikzsetfigurename{...}` you're mentioning. anyway, I also found `\tikzsetnextfilename{...}` and used that to add random names to all diagrams